# Python get a value from numpy.ndarray by [index]

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
ze=np.zeros(3)
print(ze[0]) # ->  0
```

I am pretty new to Python (3.5.2)

I learned 'list' in python and to show the i th element in list1

```
print (list1[i])
```

but, even 'np.zeros(3)' is ndarray,  a class in NumPy,
 it can be used as the 'list' like above.

What is happening on that?

I am pretty new but I have worked on Java..so I hope the issues can be understood...

I guess this question is too early for one who just learned range() and not known how to define functions(methods?)..

But please let me know how to achieve the access by operator [].

Maybe it will be usefull, when I really start to Python.

Comment: I didn't really understood your question. But `np.zeros(3)` creates a list of 3 elements to value 0. So it is correct to access with [] to your 3 elements. `ze[0]`, `ze[1]` and `ze[2]`.

Comment: My question was no good.. I asked how to make it possible to access by [] with a class made by a user. I, new to Python, mean  I thought [] can only be used for the 'list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a class that can return a value using the [] operator. Then implement the `__getitem__(self, key)` function in the class, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know.